What are the allusions in Dana Gioia’s poem “The Underworld”?
Dana Gioia’s poem The Underworld is about a trip to Hell (on the Western Line of the London Underground).
In his book Meet Me at the Lighthouse, he gives some notes on this poem, which say

This sequence makes allusions to Virgil, Seneca, Dante, Christopher Marlowe, W.B. Yeats, and T.S. Eliot, as well as Kelly Link and Clive Barker.

What are these allusions?
Some of them are easy to find. The epigraph for the poem is

Faciils descensus Averno.
[Descending into Hell is easy.] — Virgil,

and the first line paraphrases this quote:

It isn't difficult to visit Hell.

The allusion to Christopher Marlowe is a quote from his play Faust, in Stanza IV:

“Why this is Hell, nor am I out of it,”

The allusion to W.B. Yeats is a line in Stanza XVI, taken from his poem The Second Coming:

Surely some revelation is at hand,

Kelly Link wrote a short story Flying Lessons
which contains (in the chapter Going to Hell: Instructions and Advice) the following instructions for getting to Hell:

When you arrive at Kings Cross, go down into the Underground. Get on the Northern line. Sit in the last car. Speak to no one. Don’t fall asleep.
The Northern line stops at Angel, at London Bridge, at Elephant and Castle, Tooting Broadway. The last marked station is Morden: stay in your seat. Other passengers will remain with you in the car. Speak to no one.

These instructions are repeated (with several alterations) in Stanza I.
The Seneca allusion is undoubtedly to the poem Hercules Furens, which Dana Gioia has translated (as The Madness of Hercules). Gioia remarks

I chose Hercules Furens to translate because of its fabulous account of the Underworld. The play was the missing link between Virgil’s Aeneid and Dante’s Inferno.

In Hercules Furens, Hercules visits Hell. When he comes back, he goes mad and kills his family. Is the allusion to Seneca then simply the lines from Stanza X?

The truths that darkness taught infected them,
Clouding their minds and goading their descent.
A few returned, the legendary heroes.

Or is there some more specific allusion to Seneca than this?
Dante, of course, wrote an entire epic poem about a visit to Hell. Again, is the allusion to Dante's Inferno in general, or is there some more specific allusion.
Finally, what are the allusions to T.S. Eliot and Clive Barker?

Maybe the Clive Barker reference is to the bishop whose mouth is sewn shut.

Maybe the T.S. Eliot allusion is to The Hollow Men, with the lines "Sleep, and the memories of life will fade. //
You wake a dry husk turning in the wind."  But this, and the Clive Barker allusion suggested by @ClaraDíazSanchez don't seem as explicit as the other allusions, so I'd like to wait and see if anybody comes up with something more explicit.

@ClaraDíazSanchez: I can't find a bishop whose mouth is sewn shut in the works of Clive Barker. (I've just done some cursory Googling; I'm not about to read Barker's horror novels to answer this question.) Do you know that one exists, or was this just a guess?

I'm no expert on Clive Barker's works either, but I remembered one of the cenobites in "Hellraiser" has her(?) lips sewn shut. I doubt that it was a bishop though.

I have identified the Dante allusion and the Seneca allusion, and I have found something that might be the Clive Barker allusion. Here they are:

The allusion to Dante is in the last stanza, titled Disappointments. This stanza contains the line

No bleeding thorns, no waters of oblivion,

Dante's epic poem Inferno contains bleeding thorns. From Inferno, Canto XIII:

Then I stretched out my hand
and plucked a twig from a tall thorn-bush,
and its stem cried out: ‘Why do you break me?’
When it ran dark with blood
it cried again: ‘Why do you tear me?
Have you no pity in you?”

(From the Robert Hollander translation.)
Virgil explains that suicides are transformed into thorn bushes, and that breaking a twig of such a tree will cause it intense pain.

I felt sure that the Seneca allusion was to the play Hercules Furens, which contains a description of Hercules' trip to Hell, and which Gioia translated (as The Madness of Hercules), and indeed it was. The allusion in The Underworld is in Stanza XII:

Why willingly depart the rain, the stars,
The gold abundance of the morning sky,
The dusty ripeness of the apple bough?

Seneca's play contains the lines, describing Hell:

Not so: no joyful fields with verdure shine,
No ripening grain waves gently in the breeze,
No stately trees bear apple-laden boughs;

(from the Frank Justus Miller translation).

Finally, I have a candidate for the Clive Barker allusion. In The Damnation Game, there is a passage which is in several places on the internet, so it seems to be relatively well-known:

Hell is reimagined by each generation. Its terrain is surveyed for absurdities and remade in a fresher mould; its terrors are scrutinised and, if necessary, reinvented to suit the current climate of atrocity; its architecture is redesigned to appall the eye of the modern damned. In an earlier age Pandemonium — the first city of Hell — stood on a laval mountain while lightning tore the clouds above it and beacons burned on its wails to summon the fallen angels, Now, such spectacle belongs to Hollywood. Hell stands transposed. No lightning, no pits of fire.

The sentence "No lightning, no pits of fire," is vaguely similar to the last stanza of The Underworld:

XVII. Disappointments
No fire, no furies, no ferryman,
No bleeding thorns, no waters of oblivion,
No triple-headed dog to guard the gate,
No gate at all as far as you can tell,

Is this the allusion to Clive Barker, or is there another, more convincing, allusion? I don't know.
In the comments, Clara Diaz Sanchez proposes that the Clive Barker reference is the bishop whose mouth is sewn shut. However, this also seems unconvincing; while there may be people whose mouths are sewn shut in Clive Barker's books, it doesn't seem that any of them are bishops. On the other hand, there are a lot of weirdly deformed people from Hell called cenobites in Clive Barker's, books, and it's possible that the lines from Stanza V:

    .       .       .       .        .      the blue-eyed girl
Who strokes the tiny scars along her arm,
The man with twenty fingers on his hand,
Or the tall bishop with his mouth sewn shut?
They sit like oracles bereft of utterance.
Theirs are the secrets Hell exists to hide.

might be a reference to them, even if these aren't the exact cenobites that Clive Barker described.

This leaves the allusion to T.S. Eliot, which I have not identified.
